# How to pass viewModel string value with umlauts/special characters to controller action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I am storing a ViewModel string value into a JS variable for use in a controller action such as:

```
var info = '@Model.CompanyInfo';
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ControllerAction", "Controller")/?id=" + mId + &info=" + info;
```

The controller action works fine, however when `@Model.CompanyInfo` contains umlauts/special characters these characters are converted (i.g. ö is converted to `&#246;`). Then the controller action does not recieve the entire string that is contained in `var info`. It looks like **everything is lost behind the position of the first special character/umlaut**.

I have tried to encode/decode the string, but I could not get it to work.

**How can I pass the entire string to the controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.Raw` will preserve given character and `encodeURIComponent` will properly pass it to controller

```
@{
    var umlaut = "ö";
}
<script>
    var umlautStr = '@Html.Raw(umlaut)';
    console.log(umlautStr);

    window.location = '/home/index?q=' + encodeURIComponent(umlautStr);
</script>
```

[image]

If for some reason you don't like `Html.Raw` approach, you could use custom function to handle German characters.

```js
    function replacer(message) {
        return message
            .replace(/&#220;/g, '\334')//Ü (Uppercase u with umlaut)
            .replace(/&#214;/g, '\326')//Ö (Uppercase o with umlaut)
            .replace(/&#196;/g, '\304')//Ä (Uppercase a with umlaut)
            .replace(/&#252;/g, '\374')//ü (Lowercase u with umlaut)
            .replace(/&#246;/g, '\366')//ö (Lowercase o with umlaut)
            .replace(/&#228;/g, '\344');//ä (Lowercase a with umlaut)
    
    }
```

Comment: However, does not work for &.  Again the string is truncated at &

Comment: You do need to be careful with @Html.Raw - if your `CompanyInfo` is at any time entered by a user, they can enter strange things, such as `';location.href="https://stackoverflow.com/"//` - and, using the code above, every time someone tries to view your company info page, they get SO instead...

Comment: @Yegor: In my case encodeURIComponent does not seem to be needed. And it does not resolve the problem with &

Comment: @freedomn-m: CompanyInfo does not come from user input. I think it is save to use in my case.

Comment: Hence "be careful" not "don't use" :)

Comment: @Manu '&' character works perfectly fine for me with `encodeURIComponent` - it gets transformed into %26

Comment: Sorry, my mistake:  Model.CompanyInfo is a hidden field in the razor view, I did not see that the string was truncted whenever a '&' was present in the string. Now I realized that the truncation happens already at the point where Model.CompanyInfo gets fetched by the view controller. I fixed the view controller and then the subsequent url action in the razor view acts correctly.